# How to load with jQuery only once, then use selectors without additional HTTP requests

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, load

Could you help me with this code, please?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#div1').load('/text.php #p1');
jQuery('#div2').load('/text.php #p2');
jQuery('#div3').load('/text.php #p3');
jQuery('#div4').load('/text.php #p4')
});
```

When using this code, a browser makes a HTTP request any time when it needs to open the same file `text.php`. The difference is only in selectors. Can you tell me if it's possible to load the file `text.php` only once, and then use its selectors to fill the content of different `div`s?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a get request then try something like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.get('/text.php', function (html) {
        var $html = $('<div />', {
            html: html
        });
        $('#div1').empty().append($html.find('#p1'))
        $('#div2').empty().append($html.find('#p2'))
        $('#div3').empty().append($html.find('#p3'))
        $('#div4').empty().append($html.find('#p4'))
    }, 'html')
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code and can see a request with the content of a file in the console, however the content doesn't appear in a DIV.

Comment: @PhilipSorokin can you share the html sample

Comment: @PhilipSorokin where is the said script in the test page

Comment: @PhilipSorokin it is because your html has a flat structure... so either try the updated answer or use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: Thank you, Arun. Tried the updated answer — it works!